# Use LongClickListener in ListActivity

Tags: java, android, android-listview, listactivity

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

The normal method works fine for me but is there also a method for a long click?
Since I am on a ListActivity I cant use:

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener()
```

because i cant initialize listView bc of ListActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found a nice solution for it:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int row, long arg3) {

             System.out.println("REIHE "+row);
             return true;

        }
    });
```